# Bootstrap Issue: Container Fluid Not being 100% Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a real estate website project. I am trying to achieve 100% width by using .container-fluid. I have already followed several solutions mentioned on Stack Overflow. But I am unable to do it.

Here is the screenshot of the issue:
[image]

Here is the Code Pen link:
https://codepen.io/kanan292/pen/bmZjeJ

Here are HTML codes:

```
<section id="property-section">

                    <div class="container-fluid">
                    </div>
            </section>
```

Here are the CSS codes that I tried to fix the issue:

```
.container-fluid{
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.container-fluid{
padding-left: 0 !important;
padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Or for no padding in any direction

```
.container-fluid{
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a n00b question but someone should help you anyways. Just add `!important` to make sure that your css overrides the previous styling.

```
.container-fluid{
   padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap by default provides a padding of `15px` even if the width of container-fluid tend to be `100%`.

if you don't want that padding just override the bootstrap default-style, using the code below.

```
.container-fluid{
   padding: 0 !important; 
}
```

**Note:**
The `!important` rule overrides that particular property from being cascaded.